# Retrieving and writing a file to system

Tags: php, file, file-io

What's the simplest way in PHP, to:

1. Retrieve a file from an external URL (http://test.com/thisfile)?
2. If successful, delete local file `/root/xml/test.xml`.
3. Rename downloaded file to `test.xml`.
4. Write new file to `/root/xml/` folder.

This will be a private script, so security or error handling are not important concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$contents = file_get_contents( 'http://test.com/testfile' );
if( $contents ) {
     $file = '/root/xml/test.xml';
     unlink( $file );
     file_put_contents( $contents, $file ); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming correct configuration,

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://test.com/thisfile');
if($file) {
    unlink('/root/xml/test.xml');
    file_put_contents('/root/xml/test.xml');
}
```

Or something along those lines.